# team_explorer.bat not found when using Developer Powershell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

When I launch the Developer PowerShell for VS 2022, I get this error.

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer PowerShell v17.2.4
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
Enter-VsDevShell : [ERROR:team_explorer.bat] Directory not found : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer"
At line:1 char:133
+ ... Shell.dll"; Enter-VsDevShell 32781b11 -SkipAutomaticLocation -DevCmdA ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enter-VsDevShell], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DevCmdError,Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.Commands.EnterVsDevShellCommand
```

The CLI then resumes, but how do I fix this error? It shows up everytime I launch the shell

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am new to windows. Been using Linux and OSX for the past few years. So please let me know I need to add more info.

Comment: I created an empty folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer` and it stopped throwing the error.

Comment: I reported this issue on developercommunity [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VsDevCmdbat--Enter-VsDevShell-in-Build/10113562)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be some kind of bug, but I'll confirm that creating the mentioned directory works around it.